# Hot topics in mathematical statistics

Tags: mathematical-statistics

What are some hot topics that mathematical statistics researchers are studying now?

Comment: I am pretty sure there has been question like this one already. However, you may have a look at papers to be published at AOS http://www.imstat.org/aos/ this should give you ideas of "hot" topics ?

Comment: This is a related question (though asking for "important" topics, which is slightly distinct from "hot"/popular topics): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/what-are-the-big-problems-in-statistics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Persi Diaconis wrote an article on "Mathematical Statistics" in the Princeton Companion of Mathematics.  He discusses several ongoing research areas in mathematical statistics, including the search for high-dimensional admissible estimators (Stein's paradox).

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully, modelling the dynamics of tumor progression qualifies for this:

Anderson & Quaranta. [Integrative mathematical oncology](http://www.nature.com/nrc/journal/v8/n3/abs/nrc2329.html). Nature Reviews Cancer, 2008.