# What are the main theorems in Machine (Deep) Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, mathematical-statistics

Al Rahimi has recently given [a very provocative talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi1Yry33TQE) in NIPS 2017 comparing current Machine Learning to Alchemy. One of his claims is that we need to get back to theoretical developments, to have simple theorems proving foundational results.

When he said that, I started looking for the main theorems for ML, but could not find a good reference making sense of the main results. So here is my question: what are the current main mathematical theorems (theory) in ML/DL and what do they prove? I would guess Vapnik's work would go somewhere here. As an extra, what are the main theoretical open problems?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is not too broad. "Main" is pretty subjective and ML is very diverse and non-homogenous field, so this makes it very broad...

Comment: @Tim well since it's community wiki now, this question can be a repository of the main theorems for reference, even though there's some subjectivity on it

Comment: Being community wiki does not make it not-too-broad...

Comment: @Tim  I don't think it is that broad, it's like the main theorems for classical statistics, there can be some discussion over one or the other, but the community agrees with the most important ones

Comment: @Tim  there's some agreement in the ML community of the main capstone achievements in theory

Comment: I do think this is too broad. I'm not sure whether or not being CW should 'save' it from closure--I could go either way.  How should we interpret the scope of "machine learning" here? Everyone seems to be thinking of predictive models; I don't see anything that covers clustering, reinforcement learning, things pertaining to adaptive sorting algorithms, etc. How should "main" be ascertained? Etc. (cc, @Tim)

Comment: @Tim This thead is of a kind with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/what-are-the-big-problems-in-statistics/2415#2415 ("What are the big problems in statistics?").

Comment: It's a bit broad. Could you at least specify a subset of Machine Learning? If we limit ourselves to Deep Learning, or at least to supervised learning, one could attempt an answer. But if you insist on something like "Mathematics of Machine Learning", an answer will take ages to write.

Comment: In light of @whuber's example analog, I'm inclined to say this should stay open as CW, especially if this can be limited to a specific subset of ML, such as *supervised learning*, as DeltaV requests.

Comment: @DeltaIV Note that "Deep" is in the title.

Comment: @amoeba true, but "Machine" also is...if the title had been "What are the main theorems in Deep Learning?" a more concise (better?) answer may have been possible. Anyway, I tried to cover Machine Learning in general (and Deep Learning in particular) the best I could.

Comment: Understanding this question was the topic of a recent series of lectures hosted by David Donoho: see https://stats385.github.io/.

Comment: @user795305 do you think you could summarize some of the main theorems they've discussed?

Comment: Al Rahimi was not talking about machine learning in general, but deep learning (he was being rewarded for theoretical work he had done in ML).

Comment: The current interest in deep learning is primarily driven by their success on 'signal processing' tasks: image and speech recognition.  I think what is missing from this discussion is an understanding of the statistics of images/speech etc (and therefore why conv nets have been successful).

Comment: @seanv507 good point.The problem is that the usual hand-waving arguments such as "convolution is sensitive to local features, max pooling help to get equivariance", etc.,don't qualify for a question focused on actual **theorems**. I'll add a couple, but if you have specific suggestions I'd love to know (or just write your own answer, of course).

Comment: @seanv507 indeed, he (and Ben Recht, I think, who didn't come?) were awarded a prize for random features in kernel machines. That's also one of the reasons why I asked the OP to edit her/his question to "What are the main theorems in Deep Learning?". However, as the question currently stands, an answer has to cover ML in general (unfortunately).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, this question seems too broad to me, but I'll make an attempt to an answer. In order to set some boundaries, I will start with a little math which underlies most of ML, and then concentrate on recent results for DL.

---

The **bias-variance tradeoff** is referred to in countless books, courses, MOOCs, blogs, tweets, etc. on ML, so we can't start without mentioning it:

$$\mathbb{E}[(Y-\hat{f}(X))^2|X=x_0]=\sigma_{\epsilon}^2+\left(\mathbb{E}\hat{f}(x_0)-f(x_0)\right)^2+\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{f}(x_0)-\mathbb{E}\hat{f}(x_0)\right)^2\right]=\text{Irreducible error + Bias}^2 \text{ + Variance}$$

Proof here: [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/ElemStatLearn/)

---

The **Gauss-Markov Theorem** (yes, linear regression will remain an important part of Machine Learning, no matter what: deal with it) clarifies that, when the linear model is true and some assumptions on the error term are valid, OLS has the minimum mean squared error (which in the above expression is just $\text{Bias}^2 \text{ + Variance}$) only among the *unbiased* linear estimators of the linear model. Thus there could well be linear estimators with bias (or nonlinear estimators) which have a better mean square error, and thus a better expected prediction error, than OLS. And this paves the way to all the regularization arsenal (ridge regression, LASSO, weight decay, etc.) which is a workhorse of ML. A proof is given here (and in countless other books):
[https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Statistical-Models-James-Stapleton/dp/0470231467](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470231467)

Probably more relevant to the explosion of regularization approaches, as noted by Carlos Cinelli in the comments, and definitely more fun to learn about, is the **James-Stein theorem**. Consider $n$ independent, same variance but **not** same mean Gaussian random variables:

$$X_i|\mu_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\theta_i,\sigma^2), \quad i=1,\dots,n$$

in other words, we have an $n-$components Gaussian random vector $\mathbf{X}\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\theta},\sigma^2I)$. We have one sample $\mathbf{x}$ from $\mathbf{X}$ and we want to estimate $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. The MLE (and also UMVUE) estimator is obviously $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{MLE}=\mathbf{x}$. Consider the James-Stein estimator

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{JS}= \left(1-\frac{(n-2)\sigma^2}{||\mathbf{x}||^2}\right)\mathbf{x} $$

Clearly, if $(n-2)\sigma^2\leq||\mathbf{x}||^2$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{JS}$ *shrinks* the MLE estimate towards zero. The **James-Stein theorem** states that for $n\geq4$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{JS}$ *strictly dominates* $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{MLE}$, i.e., it has lower MSE $\forall \ \boldsymbol{\theta}$. Pheraps surprisingly, even if we shrink towards any other constant $\boldsymbol{c}\neq \mathbf{0}$, $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{JS}$ still dominates $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}_{MLE}$. Since the $X_i$ are independent, it may seem weird that, when trying to estimate  the height of three unrelated persons, including a sample from the number of apples produced in Spain, may improve our estimate *on average*. The key point here is "on average": the mean square error for the simultaneous estimation of all the components of the parameter vector is smaller, but the square error for one or more components  may well be larger, and indeed it often is, when you have "extreme" observations.

Finding out that MLE, which was indeed the "optimal" estimator for the univariate estimation case, was dethroned for multivariate estimation, was quite a shock at the time, and led to a great interest in shrinkage, better known as regularization in ML parlance. One could note some similarities with mixed models and the concept of "borrowing strength": there is indeed some connection, as discussed here

[Unified view on shrinkage: what is the relation (if any) between Stein's paradox, ridge regression, and random effects in mixed models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/unified-view-on-shrinkage-what-is-the-relation-if-any-between-steins-paradox)

Reference: [James, W., Stein, C., *Estimation with Quadratic Loss*. Proceedings of the Fourth Berkeley Symposium on Mathematical Statistics and Probability, Volume 1: Contributions to the Theory of Statistics, 361--379, University of California Press, Berkeley, Calif., 1961](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsmsp/1200512173)

---

Principal Component Analysis is key to the important topic of dimension reduction, and it's based on the **Singular Value Decomposition**: for each $N\times p$ real matrix $X$ (although the theorem easily generalizes to complex matrices) we can write

$$X=UDV^T$$

where $U$ of size $N \times p$ is orthogonal, $D$ is a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix with nonnegative diagonal elements and $U$ of size $p \times p$ is again orthogonal. For proofs and algorithms on how to compute it see: Golub, G., and Van Loan, C. (1983), *Matrix computations*, John Hopkins University press, Baltimore.

---

**Mercer's theorem** is the founding stone for a lot of different ML methods: thin plate splines, support vector machines, the Kriging estimate of a Gaussian random process, etc. Basically, is one of the two theorems behind the so-called *kernel trick*. Let $K(x,y):[a,b]\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a symmmetric continuous function or kernel. if $K$ is positive semidefinite, then it admits an orthornormal basis of eigenfunctions corresponding to nonnegative eigenvalues:

$$K(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\gamma_i \phi_i(x)\phi_i(y)$$

The importance of this theorem for ML theory is testified by the number of references it gets in famous texts, such as for example [Rasmussen & Williams text on Gaussian processes](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf).

Reference: [J. Mercer, *Functions of positive and negative type, and their connection with the theory of integral equations.* Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Containing Papers of a Mathematical or Physical Character, 209:415-446, 1909](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/roypta/209/441-458/415.full.pdf)

There is also a simpler presentation in Konrad Jörgens, *Linear integral operators*, Pitman, Boston, 1982.

---

The other theorem which, together with Mercer's theorem, lays out the theoretical foundation of the kernel trick, is the **representer theorem**. Suppose you have a sample space $\mathcal{X}$ and a symmetric positive semidefinite kernel $K: \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$. Also let $\mathcal{H}_K$ be the RKHS associated with $K$. Finally, let $S=\{\mathbb{x}_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a training sample. The theorem says that among all functions $f\in \mathcal{H}_K$, which all admit an infinite representation in terms of eigenfunctions of $K$ because of Mercer's theorem, the one that minimizes the regularized risk always has a finite representation in the basis formed by the kernel evaluated at the $n$ training points, i.e.

$$\min_{f \in \mathcal{H}_K} \sum_{i=1}^n L(y_i,f(x_i))+\lambda||f||^2_{\mathcal{H}_K}=\min_{\{c_j\}_1^\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n L(y_i,\sum_j^\infty c_j\phi_j(x_i))+\lambda\sum_j^\infty \frac{c_j^2}{\gamma_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i K(x,x_i)$$

(the theorem is the last equality). References: Wahba, G. 1990, *Spline Models for Observational Data*, SIAM, Philadelphia.

---

The **universal approximation theorem** has been already cited by user Tobias Windisch and is much less relevant to Machine Learning than it is to functional analysis, even if it may not seem so at a first glance. The problem is that the theorem only says that such a network exists, but:

- it doesn't give any correlation between the size $N$ of the hidden layer and some measure of complexity of the target function $f(x)$, such as for example Total Variation. If $f(x)=\sin(\omega x):[0,2\pi]\to[-1,1]$ and the $N$ required for a fixed error $\epsilon$ growed exponentially with $\omega$, then single hidden layer neural networks would be useless.
- it doesn't say if the network $F(x)$ is *learnable*. In other words assume that given $f$ and $\epsilon$, we know that a size $N$ NN will approximate $f$ with the required tolerance in the hypercube. Then by using training sets of size $M$  and a learning procedure such as for example back-prop, do we have any guarantee that by increasing $M$ we can recover $F$?
- finally, and worse of them all, it doesn't say anything about the prediction error of neural networks. What we're really interested in is an estimate of the prediction error, at least averaged over all training sets of size $M$. The theorem doesn't help in this respect.

A smaller pain point with the Hornik's version of this theorem is that it doesn't hold for ReLU activation functions. However, Bartlett has since proved  an extended version which covers this gap.

---

Until now, I guess all the theorems I considered were well-known to anybody. So now it's time for the fun stuff :-) Let's see a few *Deep Learning* theorems:

Assumptions:

- the deep neural network $\Phi(X,W)$ (for fixed $W$, $\Phi_W(X)$ is the function which associates the inputs of the neural network with its outputs) and the regularization loss $\Theta(W)$ are both sums of *positively homogeneous functions* of the same degree
- the loss function $L(Y,\Phi(X,W))$ is convex and at least once differentiable in $X$, in a compact set $S$

Then:

- any local minimum for $L(Y,\Phi(X,W))+\lambda\Theta(W)$ such that a subnetwork of $\Phi(X,W)$ has zero weights, is a global minimum (**Theorem 1**)
- above a critical network size, local descent will always converge to a global minimum from any initialization (**Theorem 2**).

This is very interesting: CNNs made only of convolutional layers, ReLU, max-pooling, fully connected ReLU and linear layers are *positively homogenous* functions, while if we include sigmoid activation functions, this isn't true anymore, which may partly explain the superior performance in some applications of ReLU + max pooling with respect to sigmoids. What's more, the theorems only hold if also $\Theta$ is positively homogeneous in $W$ of the same degree as $\Phi$. Now, the fun fact is that  $l_1$ or $l_2$ regularization, although positively homogeneous, don't have the same degree of $\Phi$ (the degree of $\Phi$, in the simple CNN case mentioned before, increases with the number of layers). Instead, more modern regularization methods such as batch normalization and path-SGD do correspond to a positively homogeneous regularization function of the same degree as $\Phi$, and dropout, while not fitting this framework exactly, holds strong similarities to it. This may explain why, in order to get high accuracy with CNNs, $l_1$ and $l_2$ regularization are not enough, but we need to employ all kinds of devilish tricks, such as dropout and batch normalization! To the best of my knowledge, this is the closest thing to an explanation of the efficacy of batch normalization, which is otherwise very obscure, as correctly noted by Al Rahimi in his talk.

Another observation that some people make, based on **Theorem 1**, is that it could explain why ReLU work well, even with the problem of *dead neurons*. According to this intuition, the fact that, during training, some ReLU neurons "die" (go to zero activation and then never recover from that, since for $x<0$ the gradient of ReLU is zero) is "a feature, not a bug", because if we have reached a minimum and a full subnetwork has died, then we're provably reached a global minimum (under the hypotheses of **Theorem 1**). I may be missing something, but I think this interpretation is far-fetched. First of all, during training ReLUs can "die" well before we have reached a local minimun. Secondly, it has to be proved that when ReLU units "die", they always do it over a full subnetwork: the only case where this is trivially true is when you have just **one** hidden layer, in which case of course each single neuron is a subnetwork. But in general I would be very cautious in seeing "dead neurons" as a good thing.

References:

B. Haeffele and R. Vidal, *Global optimality in neural network training*,
In IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition,
2017.

B. Haeffele and R. Vidal. *Global optimality in tensor factorization,
deep learning, and beyond*, arXiv, abs/1506.07540, 2015.

---

Image classification requires learning representations which are invariant (or at least robust, i.e., very weakly sensitive) to various transformations such as  location, pose, viewpoint, lighting, expression, etc. which are commonly present in natural images, but do not contain info for the classification task. Same thing for speech recognition: changes in pitch, volume, pace, accent. etc. should not lead to a change in the classification of the word. Operations such as convolution, max pooling, average pooling, etc., used in CNNs, have exactly this goal, so intuitively we expect that they would work for these applications. But do we have theorems to support this intuition? There is a **vertical translation invariance theorem**, which, notwithstanding the name, has nothing to do with translation in the vertical direction, but it's basically a result which says that features learnt in following layers get more and more invariant, as the number of layers grows. This is opposed to an older **horizontal translation invariance theorem** which however holds for scattering networks, but **not** for CNNs.
The theorem is very technical, however:

- assume $f$ (your input image) is square-integrable
- assume your filter commutes with the translation operator $T_t$, which maps the input image $f$ to a translated copy of itself $T_t f$. A learned convolution kernel (filter) satisfies this hypothesis.
- assume all filters, nonlinearities and pooling in your network satisfy a so-called *weak admissibility condition*, which is basically some sort of weak regularity and boundedness conditions. These conditions are satisfied by learned convolution kernel (as long as some normalization operation is performed on each layer), ReLU, sigmoid, tanh, etc, nonlinearities, and by average pooling, but **not** by max-pooling. So it covers some (not all) real world CNN architectures.
- Assume finally that each layer $n$ has a pooling factor $S_n> 1$, i.e., pooling is applied in each layer and effectively discards information. The condition $S_n\geq 1 $ would also suffice for a weaker version of the theorem.

Indicate with $\Phi^n(f)$ the output of layer $n$ of the CNN, when the input is $f$. Then finally:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|||\Phi^n(T_f f)-\Phi^n(f)|||=0$$

(the triple bars are not an error) which basically means that each layer learns features which become more and more invariant, and in the limit of an infinitely deep network we have a perfectly invariant architecture. Since CNNs have a finite number of layers, they're not perfectly translation-invariant, which is something well-known to practitioners.

Reference: [T. Wiatowski and H. Bolcskei, *A Mathematical Theory of Deep Convolutional Neural Networks for Feature Extraction*, arXiv:1512.06293v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06293.pdf).

---

To conclude, numerous bounds for the generalization error of a Deep Neural Network based on its Vapnik-Chervonkensis dimension or on the Rademacher complexity grow with the number of parameters (some even exponentially), which means they can't explain why DNNs work so well in practice even when the number of parameters is considerably larger than the number of training samples. As a matter of fact, VC theory is not very useful in Deep Learning.

Conversely, some results from last year bound the generalization error of a DNN classifier with a quantity which is independent of the neural network's depth and size, but depends only on the structure of the training set and the input space. Under some pretty technical assumptions on the learning procedure, and on the training set and input space, but with very little assumptions on the DNN (in particular, CNNs are fully covered), then with probability at least $1-\delta$, we have

$$\text{GE} \leq \sqrt{2\log{2}N_y\frac{\mathcal{N_{\gamma}}}{m}}+\sqrt{\frac{2\log{(1/\delta)}}{m}}$$

where:

- $\text{GE}$ is the generalization error, defined as the difference between the expected loss (the average loss of the learned classifier on all possible test points) and the empirical loss (just the good ol' training set error)
- $N_y$ is the number of classes
- $m$ is the size of the training set
- $\mathcal{N_{\gamma}}$ is the *covering number* of the data, a quantity related to the structure of the input space and to the the minimal separation among points of different classes in the training set. Reference:

J. Sokolic, R. Giryes, G. Sapiro, and M. Rodrigues. *Generalization
error of invariant classifiers*. In AISTATS, 2017

Comment: +1. Great answer, the last part is very intriguing. In the first part, Mercer's theorem looks just like SVD that you presented just above.

Comment: @amoeba, you're right, but 1) not all readers are as math-savy as you, that they would immediately recognize the similitude between SVD, Karhunen- Loeve expansion and Mercer's theorem. Also 2) the other theorem from Functional Analysis which "powers" the kernel trick, and which I chose not to include, is harder to explain than Mercer's theorem, and I already busted my Saturday :-) Maybe I'll add it tomorrow!

Comment: +1 obviously but I was ready to say too that Mercer's theorem is a bit far fetched and supersedes the SVD... By the way, the proper reference is: J. Mercer, "*Functions of positive and negative type, and their connection with the theory of integral equations.*" Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Containing Papers of a Mathematical or Physical Character, 209:415-446, 1909. ([Link to paper](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/roypta/209/441-458/415.full.pdf))

Comment: Gauss Markov seems out of place, never saw anyone care about BLUE in the ML community.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for the upvote. Now, let's not get too carried away with the similarities between Mercer's theorem & SVD! They're closely related but SVD is **not** just a consequence of Mercer's theorem  when applied to linear operators between finite-dimensional spaces. SVD is valid for *any* (finite-d) linear operator, Mercer's theorem is only valid for symmetric *positive-semidefinite* kernels. Anyway, since you're the second one to dislike that, I will modify that part of the answer.

Comment: @usεr11852 concerning the reference, for old theorems I tend to avoid the original reference like a plague, because it's usually expressed in such archaic form as to be useless to contemporary readers. For example, I chose not to link the book by Markov (in Russian!) for the Gauss-Markov theorem. Anyway, I'll follow your suggestion and correct the reference, even though I think Jorgens' presentation is simpler.

Comment: I agree that as a general rule the original (archaic) reference usually has tedious notation. That said, Mercer's paper is actually surprisingly modern in that aspect and I added it exactly because of that. :) (I said originally, this a very good answer, this is just a commentary after the upvote)

Comment: @usεr11852 I agree with the modernity of the paper, that's why you convinced me :)

Comment: I like Mercer's theorem here, don't remove it. And why not have both links? Just add smth like `See [here] for a modern exposition`, or vice versa, "for the original paper".

Comment: @CarlosCinelli are you pheraps saying that Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman are not part of the ML community? Anyway, all serious ML books (Bishop, Murphy,  Mostafa & Ismail, etc.) dedicate at least a chapter to linear regression, so at least one theorem on it is going to stay. I chose Gauss-Markov because it explains in a simple case why regularization is so important for a "prediction-focused" discipline such as ML, but if you have better suggestions I'll listen.

Comment: @DeltaIV are you saying that Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman consider Gauss-Markov a main theorem in machine learning? If you want to  pick a theorem of linear regression just to mention linear regression models, that's ok, but Gauss-Markov seems more like a footnote in overall ML.

Comment: But this is just a comment on that one thing, I'm not criticizing your overall answer, and I really appreciate your effort here, I had +1'd already.

Comment: @carloscinelli you're welcome to criticize my answer, constructive criticism helps me improve it. I have here a copy of "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani & Friedman, and the only theorem in the linear models chapter is Gauss-Markov (well, ok, also the fact that with the OLS estimate is orthogonal to the residuals, but that seemed a bit too elementary to include). Despite to what it may appear, I'm not hung-up on Gauss-Markov - I'll accept suggestions for a better theorem on linear regression models.

Comment: @DeltaIV I would probably guess that James-Stein theorem showing that MLE is inadmissible was more impactful, and might have contributed to spur the literature on shrinkage estimators.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli excellent point. Murphy dedicates quite a few pages to the Stein's paradox, and I dare anyone say that Murphy is not a great reference for ML ;-) I'll put James-Stein in in the next days, as time permits.

Comment: I like this general piece on Stein's paradox by Efron, leaving here just in case: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~ckirby/brad/other/Article1977.pdf

Comment: @DeltaIV This was worth the 100 points! Just taking the opportunity to mention I have another (simpler) unanswered question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321841/what-are-variational-autoencoders-and-to-what-learning-tasks-are-they-used maybe you could check it out

Answer (score 11):

I think the following theorem that you allude to is considered to be pretty fundamental in statistical learning.

**Theorem (Vapnik and Chervonenkis, 1971)** Let $H$ be a
hypothesis class of functions from a domain $X$ to $\{0, 1\}$ and let the loss function
be the $0 − 1$ loss. Then, the following are equivalent:

1. $H$ has the uniform convergence property.
2. $H$ is PAC learnable.
3. $H$ has a finite VC-dimension.

Proved in a quantitive version here:

V.N. Vapnik and A.Y. Chervonenkis: On the uniform convergence of relative
frequencies of events to their probabilities. Theory of Probability and its Applications,
16(2): 264–280, 1971.

The version formulated above along with an nice exposition of other results from learning theory is available [here](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf):

Shalev-Shwartz, Shai, and Shai Ben-David. Understanding machine learning: From theory to algorithms. Cambridge university press, 2014.

Answer (score 6):

The Kernel Trick is a general idea that's used in a lot of places, and comes from a lot of abstract maths about Hilbert Spaces. Way too much theory for me to type (copy...) out into an answer here, but if you skim through this you can get a good idea of its rigorous underpinnings:

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~sejdinov/teaching/atml14/Theory_2014.pdf

Answer (score 5):

My favourite one is the Kraft inequality.

> **Theorem:** For any description method $C$ for finite alphabet $A = \{1,\dots, m\}$, the code word lengths $L_C(1), \dots, L_C(2)$ must satisfy the inequality $\sum_{x \in A} 2 ^{-L_C(x)} \leq 1$.

This inequality relates *compression* with *probability densities*: given a code, the length of an outcome represented by that code is the negative log probability of a model identified by the code.

Further, the no free lunch theorem for machine learning has a less well known sibling the no hyper compression theorem, which states that not all sequences can be compressed.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it a *main* theorem, but I think the following (sometimes referred to as the Universal approximation theorem) is an interesting (and at least for me surprising) one as it states the approximative power of feed-forward neural networks.

**Theorem:**
Let $\sigma$ be a nonconstant and monotinically-increasing continous function. For any continuos function $f:[0,1]^m\to\mathbb{R}$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exist an integern $N$ and an multilayer perceptron $F$ with one hidden layer having $N$ Neurons that has $\sigma$ as activation function so that

$$|F(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon$$
for all $x\in[0,1]^m$.

Of course, as this is a statement on *existence*, its impact for practitioners is negligible.

A proof can be found in  [Hornik, Approximation Capabilities of Muitilayer Feedforward Networks, Neural Networks 4 (2), 1991,](https://doi.org/10.1016/0893-6080(91)90009-T)

Comment: This theorem is a bit uninteresting as it is not particular to neural nets. Many other classes of functions share similar (and sometimes stronger) approximation properties. See for instance the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. A more interesting result would be the consistency of neural net regression in a general framework. Also, there must be known bounds on the mean generalization error in terms of the complexity of the net and the size of the training sample.

Comment: @Olivier: I totally agree. But even though this theorem is not exclusively devoted to neural networks, I still find it statement, its rigorous proof, and its implications interesting. For instance, it says that as long as you are using an activation function that has the properties stated above, the approximative capability of the network is the same (roughly speaking). Or, it says that neural networks are prune to overfitting as you can learn a lot already with one hidden layer.

Comment: It doesn't say exactly that. It only says that there *exists* a neural network with one hidden layer which can represent $f$, but it doesn't tell you anything about how $N$ grows with $m$, for example, or with some measure of complexity of $f$ (for example its total variation). It doesn't tell you if you can $learn$ the weights of your network, given data. You will find that in a lot of interesting cases $N$ is *exponentially* larger for one hidden layer networks than for multilayer (deep) networks. Which is why no one uses one hidden layer networks for ImageNet or for Kaggle.

Comment: @DeltaIV: There is a typo in the last sentence of my previous comment: the word "learn" should actually be "approximate" (otherwise, my statement about "overfitting" would make no sense). Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Yes, I interpreted that in the sense of "approximating". My point is that even if you know that you can in theory approximate any function (on a bounded hypercube) with a one hidden layer NN,  in practice it's useless in many cases. Another example: Gaussian Processes with the squared exponential kernel have the universal approximation property, but they haven't eliminated all the other regression methods, also because of the fact that for some problems the number of samples needed for  accurate approximation grows exponentially.

Comment: Just placed a bounty of 100 reps on the questions. I will choose the most comprehensive answer with supporting references, just mentioning in case you want to add something more to your answer!

Answer (score 3):

A nice post focusing on this question (specifically deep learning rather than general machine learning theorems) is here:

https://medium.com/mlreview/modern-theory-of-deep-learning-why-does-it-works-so-well-9ee1f7fb2808

It gives an accessible summary of the main emerging theorems for the ability of deep neural networks to generalize so well.